# How do I modify Eclipse code formatting for neon version

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

In Eclipse Mars, We have formatter location at "Window/Preferences/Java/Code Style/Formatter". What is the location in eclipse neon ?

Comment: This has not changed.

Comment: Probably then there is issue with eclipse mac. Recently I was using Linux. Just moved to mac os and eclipse neon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using macOS then the Preferences menu is in the 'Eclipse' top level menu (the left most application menu) rather than the 'Window' menu. Other than the placement of the top level menu the preferences are unchanged from Linux / Windows.

This is to conform with the standard macOS placement of the Preferences menu.